# Header Manipulation Cookies in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, cookies, fortify

Fortify tool is showing the Header manipulation cookies issue on the below code.

```
HttpCookie cookieexit= new HttpCookie("CheckUserNameExists");
cookieexit.Value = userName;
cookieexit.Secure = true;
Response.Cookies.Add(cookieexit);
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(userName, false));
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly related to original question.

If you use ***FormAuthentication***, it is ***not a good practice*** to create ***custom cookie name*** to keep track of logged-in username.

Instead, you want to use same cookie name ***FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName*** that *FormsAuthentication* uses.

So, you replace 5 lines of codes with the following single line -

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, false);
```

### Global.asax.cs

You then retrieve the username from cookie, and save it in both ***Principal Object*** and ***Current Thread***.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie decryptedCookie =
            Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket =
            FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(decryptedCookie.Value);

        var identity = new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
    }
}
```

You can then retrieve username literally *anywhere* in your code as long as *HttpContext.Current* is available. For example,

```
string userName = User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortify is complaining because it thinks that `userName` could have dangerous characters, such as newlines, which could (maybe) allow header manipulation attacks in the scenario of social engineering/phishing attacks.

I'm not too sure of the practicality of such attacks, but I am pretty sure that if you validate that `userName` only contains a whitelisted set of characters that exclude any whitespace, then such an attack is prevented.